# Dynamic glue operators in task group on runtime

Tags: airflow, aws-glue

I am trying to create a dag for a ETL solution where we have 4 stages to the the pipeline. We have source_2_s3,staging,dim_population,fact_loads

Each of these stages have multiple glue jobs in them that can run in parallel. I am trying to run these stages as taskgroups and passing a list of jobnames as parameters so we can create the glue operators on runtime but I am only getting one gluejob for each task group? What am I doing wrong. My code is as follows:

The yaml file contains all jobs for each task group and the gluejob script location as keyvalue pair

```
from os import path
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.glue import AwsGlueJobOperator
import yaml
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup


AwsGlueJobOperator.ui_color = "#F3D5C5"
DAG_FOLDER_PATH = path.dirname(__file__)
ENVIRONMENT = Variable.get("environment")
CONFIG_FILE_NAME = f"dwh_config_{ENVIRONMENT}.yml"

with open(path.join(DAG_FOLDER_PATH, CONFIG_FILE_NAME), 'r') as fl:
    cfg = yaml.safe_load(fl)["dwh"]
    aws_conn_id = cfg["aws"]["aws_conn_id"]
    glue_scripts_bucket_name = cfg["glue"]["app"]["bucket_name"]
    src1_tg = cfg["glue"]["app"]["src1_taskgroup"]
    src2_tg = cfg["glue"]["app"]["src2_taskgroup"]
    staging_tg = cfg["glue"]["app"]["staging_taskgroup"]
    dim_tg = cfg["glue"]["app"]["dim_taskgroup"]
    fact_tg = cfg["glue"]["app"]["fact_taskgroup"]


def glue_operator(list_of_jobs):
    for jobname, script_path in list_of_jobs.items():
        return AwsGlueJobOperator(
            task_id=jobname,
            dag=dag,
            aws_conn_id='aws_default',
            region_name='eu-west-2',
            job_name=jobname,
            script_location=path.join("s3://", glue_scripts_bucket_name,
                                      script_path)
        )


with DAG(dag_id="CLIENTUSAGE_DAILY_DWH_REFRESH", schedule_interval="@daily", start_date=days_ago(1),
         tags=['Clientusage']) as dag:
    batch_start_job = DummyOperator(task_id="START")

    batch_close_job = DummyOperator(task_id="END")

    with TaskGroup(group_id='src1_tg ') as src1_taskgroup:
        list = glue_operator(src1_tg)

    with TaskGroup(group_id='src2_tg') as src2_taskgroup:
        list = glue_operator(src2_tg)

    with TaskGroup(group_id='staging_tg') as staging_taskgroup:
        list = glue_operator(staging_tg)

    with TaskGroup(group_id='dim_tg') as dim_taskgroup:
        list = glue_operator(dim_tg)

    with TaskGroup(group_id='fact_tg') as fact_taskgroup:
        list = glue_operator(fact_tg)

    batch_start_job >> [src1_taskgroup,
                        src2_taskgroup] >> staging_taskgroup >> dim_taskgroup >> fact_taskgroup
        
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my function for generating dags. I forgot the basics of functions :D. Had to append all operators to an array before returning it.

```
def glue_operator(list_of_jobs):
    operators = []
    for jobname, script_path in list_of_jobs.items():
        operators.append(AwsGlueJobOperator(
            task_id=jobname,
            dag=dag,
            aws_conn_id='aws_default',
            region_name='eu-west-2',
            job_name=jobname,
            script_location=path.join("s3://", glue_scripts_bucket_name,
                                      script_path)
        ))

    return operators
```